# Can we pass parameters to signals in C?

Tags: c, sockets, signals

I am implementing a Simple Iterative TCP client/server in C. The server is infinitely listing in a loop.

Now if Ctrl+c (SIGINT) occurred at any point of time, how would I free up the resources used in server?

For example, I caught the signal in my own signal handler; how would I get socket descriptors
and buffers used in the program so as to free them?

I new to socket programming; any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: You've just hit on a great use for global variables!  Sometimes they are actually useful, contrary to what many would have you think...

Comment: @Carl: No, this is just a sign that signal handlers are a poor way to deal with input.

Comment: @R.. - Perhaps this is a glass half-full vs. half-empty debate? (I agree with both of you, incidentally.)

Comment: Set some global state in the handler, and let the "main thread" detect the state change, and then gracefully close down. Easiest way to avoid reentrancy issues.

Comment: @Jörgen - You actually don't avoid them at all that way. You have to delay (block) so you don't interrupt a non-reentrant call, then handle signals in a safe place in your main loop.

Comment: @Brian: That's basically what I said.

Comment: Interrupting a non-reentrant call is no problem as long as your signal handler only calls async-signal-safe functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't install a signal handler. Don't do anything. The default action for `SIGINT` is to terminate the process, and assuming no other processes have descriptors for your sockets, they'll all naturally be closed and cease to exist when the process terminates.

Comment: +1 Because we all got off on a tangent that didn't apply to his question. THough if he picks your answer, you owe me one. :-p

Comment: I was pretty sure of this, but kept getting sidetracked when looking it up in the standard.

Comment: @Brian: Fair enough. +1 on your answer if OP accepts mine. :-)

Comment: I am using Reentrant Functions and have mentioned socket descriptors and buffers just for the sake of an example,that's why I cant rely on Kernal to clean up all my resources........But got great points here.....Should I edit my question?

Answer (score 2):

No. The only parameter passed to your signal handler is an `int` which is the signal number.

The typical way to deal with the situation you describe is having a global variable such as `int stopAndExit` that your loop is checking. If it gets flipped to `1` by the signal handler you know to clean up and exit.

**Edit:** For a more thorough discussion prompted by comments below.

One problem with this is if you are in a non-reentrant function when the signal arrives. To deal with this, you actually want to delay (block) signals, then handle them at a point in your main loop that is safe.

**Last Edit:** Unless you have some external operations occurring that need to be cleaned up before so you guarantee you exit in a clean state ... it doesn't matter. Your socket descriptors and buffers are all going away anyway when you exit. There's no need to clean up anything.

Comment: Well, no. All of those are available to your main server loop. It just needs to check the `stopAndExit` global every time it loops. When it sees it's supposed to stop and exit, it cleans up, then exits.

Comment: Yep. I actually shouldn't have used "typical" in my answer - I'll edit. This is what Carl was eluding to in his comment above to your question. It's one of the few good uses of global variables.

Comment: Another way of dealing with it is to initialize your data, call `setjmp`, do your operations, and cleanup. In the signal handler call `longjmp`, then when you get back to `setjmp` with a nonzero value, use a `goto` (gasp! also not as evil as you thought) to skip over the operations and go straight to the cleanup. Ta-da!

Comment: @Chris. Ouch. :-D Maybe I should put "typical" back in the answer and modify my reply to be "Yep, well ... the most sane way"

Comment: @Brian - `goto`s are only really bad if you're jumping backwards. Jumping forwards is usually pretty sane.

Comment: Anyway, it's hard to (sanely) resume execution after catching a signal without using `setjmp` / `longjmp`. The rest is easy.

Comment: I agree with the first, but not the second. I generally delay signals to avoid the re-entrant problem, then handle them at a safe point in my main loop. Mind you care has to be taken so that you guarantee signals are handled in a timely manor.

Comment: @Brian - Indeed. If I could still edit that comment, I would change it to "...after catching `SIGINT` or `SIGBUS`".

Comment: @Chris: Signal handlers **cannot** call `longjump` to exit the signal handler unless you can be sure that the only functions that could be in-progress when the signal arrives are all async-signal-safe. Otherwise you will potentially corrupt the state of global data (like `malloc` bookkeeping, stdio `FILE` structures, etc.) resulting in undefined behavior and possibly even privilege compromise.

Comment: @R.. - Signal handlers can't safely do a lot of things. If you can restrict your signal handling to certain situations, you can do things more safely. Not knowing what the OP is doing can make it difficult to know what the best solution is.

Comment: I just realized that while, yes, we're having a great discussion here ... the OP's question is silly. His "socket descriptors and buffers" are all going away anyway. This is more of a discussion for if you have critical multi-stage operations occuring and you need to ensure you exit in a sane state.

Comment: @Chris: your answer itself contains "code" (in the comment) that invokes UB.

Answer (score 0):

The code in this answer is horrendously unsafe, invokes all kinds of UB, and shouldn't be used in your case. Using `setjmp` / `longjmp` in a signal handler is only remotely workable as a way to deal with null pointer dereferences, and even then it needs to be extremely limited in scope to avoid invoking UB.

<strike>Here's another possible way of dealing with cleanup:</strike>

```
static jmp_buf buf;
static int ret = 0;

void handle(int sig)
{
    ret = 1;
    longjmp(buf, 1);
}

int func(void)
{
    FILE *f = fopen(/* yadda */);

    void (*orig)(int) = signal(SIGINT, handle);

    if(setjmp(buf)) goto CLEANUP;

    // use f

  CLEANUP:
    fclose(f);
    signal(SIGINT, orig);
    return ret;
}
```

Of course, doing a whole lot of hard work in a signal handler isn't guaranteed to work by the standard, but I'm sure if you were worried about that you wouldn't be trying to handle the signal.

Comment: This solution invokes extremely dangerous undefined behavior.

Comment: To clarify, your `fclose(f)` operates on a `FILE` whose state is almost surely inconsistent (highest probability time to be interrupted by a signal is during IO). This is not just something that "isn't guaranteed by the standard" to work.

Comment: @R.. - The more I look into this the less happy I am with this answer. In my current project I use something similar to this in a much more controlled setting to handle `NULL` and invalid pointer dereferences, but a) the pointer dereferences are unavoidable as the function has to handle potentially arbitrary input cast to `void *`, and b) the critical code is two comparisons and an assignment to a boolean. Ignoring `SIGINT` or `SIGBUS` produces an infinite loop, since the instruction pointer isn't incremented, so I have to use this. I should've known better than to use this more generally.

Comment: Here's an alternate solution: In the signal handler, set a flag that the address was invalid and `mmap` a new shared page from a file over top of the page. Then when the signal returns, check that flag and unmap the page. Unfortunately however this is not thread-safe, since it's possible that something gets mapped by another thread after your `SIGSEGV` but before your `mmap`. Another solution, albeit much slower and not necessarily portable (works on most systems but UB by POSIX) is passing the address to a syscall and looking for `EFAULT`.